# Visual Studio For Mac 2022 - Cannot execute "{...}.exe"

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

I've got a problem with my Visual Studio for Mac 2022 version `17.0.4 (build 23)` when running my application and trying to debug my project.  It seems that when I try to debug the project, it gives me an error *screenshot below*. [image]

with it I can't seem to run my project in *Debug* mode because of this.  Does anyone able to fix this issue?  Please let me know sooner.

Comment: You can't execute "exe" files on the mac. Do you have custom startup settings?

Comment: I already solved it, the IDE itself is the issue.  Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same issue, shall I use 2019 instead?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is the IDE itself, I tried installing the 2019 version of Visual Studio for Mac and it seems work perfectly! I think the main reason why in Visual Studio for Mac 2022 has this problem is because doesn't support the .NET Core 3.1 because it is about to be deprecated.  I think this is why it doesn't work as expected.  Anywho, it is been solved! Hopefully anyone who across the same issue knows this.  Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac 2022 supports .NET Core 3.1 projects. Is the problem specific to that project or does a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 also have the same problem?

Comment: Same error here. Very bizarre.